# CUDA Programming and xCode

Tags: xcode, cuda

I'm completely new to Mac OS X and the main reason why I bought my new MacBook Pro R15 Retina Edition is to start studying CUDA API.

But I can't get my project build.

For example, when I create a new CUDA project, I go in the project properties and make the following changes :

Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C : LLVM GCC 4.2

Other Linker Flag : -lcuda, -lcudart

Header Search Path : /usr/local/cuda/include

Library Search Path : /usr/local/cuda/lib

When I start adding the necessary libraries in my code, everything runs fine. My code gets no typing error.

When I build the project, I get linking errors (paths shortened and message broken up for readability):

> Ld /my_test_project/Build/Products/Debug/test normal x86_64 cd /Users/Admin/Documents/test setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>
> -arch x86_64
>
> -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
>
> -L/my_test_project/Build/Products/Debug
>
> -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -F/my_test_project/Build/Products/Debug
>
> -filelist /my_test_project/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test.LinkFileList
>
> -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
>
> -lcudart
>
> -lcuda
>
> -o /my_test_project/Build/Products/Debug/test
>
> ld: file not found: @rpath/CUDA.framework/Versions/A/CUDA for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What's weird, is that when I go to the described path, I see the CUDA executable. The file is there!

When I use the cuComplex.h, which uses the  library, every single mathematical expression (such as log, cos, sin, etc...) is an "undefined variable". However, the cuComplex.h library has inside it the  library.

The driver, the SDK and toolkit are well installed and everything works like a charm. I can get the SDK examples working. But I think I miss a detail to get the whole thing working.

Comment: Hello Pierre-Luc, welcome to Stack Overflow. When you create your CUDA project, do you create it for the same architecture (32-bit / 64-bit), as the one for which you installed CUDA?

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer !

Yes, absolutely. I've installed CUDA in x64. Even if I set the property "Architecture" to 32-bit and "Valid Architecture" to i386, the same thing appears but says " ld: file not found: @rpath/CUDA.framework/Versions/A/CUDA for architecture i386"

Comment: I've even tried it to compile in terminal. I get the exact same errors.

Comment: Just for kicks, have you tried building a release version?

Comment: Maybe an issue with permissions? Maybe try compiling as root.

Comment: Maybe something is going on with that @rpath variable? See http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/

Comment: Release version of all CUDA examples in SDK work perfectly.
I tried compiling as a root. Same thing.
Will follow the link and give you updates. Thanks !

Comment: Tried with @rpath at installation directory and still getting the same error : 

    ld: file not found: @rpath/CUDA.framework/Versions/A/CUDA for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Hi Pierre-Luc, I have developef with cuda only on Linux and Windows but I may need to support OS X soon.  so I've been reading a lot.  What I see is a lot of people losing a lot of time trying to work in XCode 4.  Apprently 3 worked great. The solutions all seem to involve paths which have changed and apparently that burns a lot of people used to a preconfigured IDE.  My advice would be to get the cuda examples compiled from the command line.  It might hurt but then you will know exactly what to do the next time Apple makes breaking changes.  Good luck and please share what you learn!

Comment: Hi ! The CUDA examples have been compiled in the terminal successfully. This was the first thing that I've done after setting the CUDA drivers and everything else. This part works absolutely fine. But I still can't make my xCode recognizing my CUDA code from my book. Apparently, there is Eclipse which would be the best CUDA development environment on MacOS since nVIDIA released with CUDA 5 the nSight package. I still not tried this, I've just found that on the web. Will try this week as soon as I get time to work on this.  
Hope the nVIDIA Developer forum will be back up soon! Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem with CUDA 5.0 and Xcode 4.4.1 installed on Mountain Lion. The reason is that libcuda.dylib links CUDA.framework with rpath, which you can inspect with otool.

```
otool -L /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib
/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib:
/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib (compatibility version 1.1.0, current version 5.0.17)
@rpath/CUDA.framework/Versions/A/CUDA (compatibility version 1.1.0, current version 5.0.17)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
```

However, Xcode does not seem to recognize CUDA.framework under /Library/Frameworks. The reason is unknown. You have to add it yourself to your project.

In your project property page, click Build Phases -> Link with Libraries. Select CUDA.framework. Add it using "Add Others" if it does not appear in the list. This way you get it linked.

If you are writing Makefiles, you want to add this to fully automate the linking stage:

```
-F/Library/Frameworks -framework CUDA
```

Comment: Hi,
I also had the error as Pierre-Luc Delisle and tried to overcome this by adding the CUDA.framework as you said. Now though I get an error like this:

ld: framework not found CUDA
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help & thanks in advance...
PS: I'm running Mac OS 10.8.2 and XCode 4.5 on a Mac mini Mid 2010.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative that worked better for my setup is to change the path at libcuda like this:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change @rpath/CUDA.framework/Versions/A/CUDA \
    /Library/Frameworks/CUDA.framework/CUDA \
    /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib
```

As usual, don't paste a sudo command into your terminal if you don't understand what it does.

Comment: Read the manual for install_name_tool -change you need to revert the path back

Comment: got it.  thanks.  just swap old and new path arguments to -change option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem compiling the CUDA 6.5 examples on OS X 10.10, with Xcode 6.1. The problem happened in the examples whose Makefiles contained the line:

```
ALL_LDFLAGS += -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker CUDA
```

The fix was to tell the linker about /Library/Frameworks, so that the above was replaced with 2 lines:

```
ALL_LDFLAGS += -Xlinker -F/Library/Frameworks
ALL_LDFLAGS += -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker CUDA
```

Presumably your question is answered at this point, but this page is almost literally the only google result for "ld: framework not found CUDA" and hopefully this can save others some time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar CUDA linking issue with CUDA 8.0 and OSX 10.12 while compiling the sample files. Adding the following to the make files solved the problem.

```
LDFLAGS += -Xlinker -F/Library/Frameworks
```